# Read a PHP cookie from JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, cookies

I have a PHP script which sets a cookie called user. I need to be able to read the value from this cookie in javascript.

Can this even be done.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can access your cookies with `document.cookie` Check this link: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Comment: [w3fools](http://w3fools.com). Showing up first in search results doesn't mean they're the best.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I was thinking there would be simpler way like possibly document.cookie.myCookieName instead of searching through an array. But thanks for your help its working fine.

Answer (score 16):

There's no such thing as a "PHP cookie" or a "javascript cookie". There's just cookies, which you can access from PHP and Javascript. In JS, you'd use `document.cookie` to access the raw cookie data. There's plenty of libraries which give you finer-grained access as well,

Comment: To clarify, though, by "access from" you mean that the server gets to *set* cookies in its responses, while the client is expected to *send* existing cookies during its requests; and the cookie storage is the responsibility of the client.

Comment: the client can also set cookies, which the browser will send to the server on the next request.

Comment: Are you sure? I always thought that `set-cookie` is only a permissible field in the HTTP response. How does it even make sense: By the time the client script runs, the connection doesn't even (have to) exist any more.

Comment: @kerrek: JS can set cookies. they'll get registered in the browser, and next time a page is requested, the cookies (including the new one) will be sent to the server. basically you just do `document.cookie='cookie data here';` in JS.

Comment: Right, in that way that makes sense. Cheers.

Comment: You can not read PHP cookies from Javascript if they have been set with the 'httponly' parameter: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at `document.cookie`.

Example from  http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html

```
function createCookie(name,value,days) {
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = "; expires="+date.toUTCString();
    }
    else var expires = "";
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}

function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
}

function eraseCookie(name) {
    createCookie(name,"",-1);
}
```

---

Alternatively, if you use jQuery, there is a nice plugin:  http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Cookie

Comment: NOTE: date.toGMTString() is deprecated, use date.toUTCString() instead

Answer (score 2):

I tested it.
You can read cookie which created with php.

You only need to add '/' (path)!!

```
setcookie("username", $username, $expire, '/');
```

Answer (score 1):

Whether the cookie originates in JS or PHP should not matter. The cookie is stored for the domain, with a name and value.  It does not contain information relating to how it originated.

Here is a plugin for accessing cookies in jQuery:
http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Cookie

Comment: Good point.  Although it's not entirely true either, since JavaScript is a client-side scripting language and has no part in request headers.

Comment: I removed the comment, I think it's less helpful than I originally thought. Indeed, a cookie can originate in any number of ways: from an HTTP response via `set-cookie`; by client-side scripting action; the user could manually edit the cookie database; or it could be hard-coded into the browser; or your ISP could add one; etc. etc.

Answer (score 0):

In Drupal application which use the [Cookie Symfony library](https://github.com/symfony/http-foundation/blob/5.4/Cookie.php), you need to set specific cookie parameters in order to access it in javascript.

Using [js-cookie library](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie) which is on the drupal core, `cookies.get()` won't display the php Cookies that would have been set as HttpOnly.

You can get you cookies parameters in Application > Cookies in Chrome for example.

Answer (score -8):

Since PHP is a server side script and JavaScript runs in the browser, you'll need to send the cookie to the browser in a hidden form variable, or use an AJAX call from JavaScript to get it from the server.

Comment: That's plain nonsense. Cookie transmission is a part of the HTTP protocol, which requires no explicit action by client-side scripting.